# How to use for each to loop the usercontrol in my own container

Tags: vb.net, loops, foreach

I have a class myPanel which inherit from Panel, I have some label in myPanel, I need to change the label localtion on runtime.

```
       For Each pn As myPanel In ref.flp_balance.Controls
            If ref.flp_balance.VerticalScroll.Visible Then
                pn.label.Left = ref.flp_balance.Right - 160
            Else
                pn.label.Left  = ref.flp_balance.Right - 135
            End If
       Next
```

I get this error when run until for each

"InvalidCastException was unhandle"

"Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' to type 'XXX.myPanel'."

Comment: Are you sure that the controls collection of _flp_balance_ contains only elements of type _myPanel_ ? And what is the _flp_balance_ ?

Comment: flp_balance contain Panel and myPanel

Comment: If not every control in that container is that type then specify to use only that type, i.e. `In ref.flp_balance.Controls.OfType(Of MyPanel)()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the container *flp_balance* contains also normal Panels, not only elements of type *myPanel* If this is not a design error then you could change your foreach loop introducing the extension [OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to return only the elements of the required type.

```
For Each pn As myPanel In ref.flp_balance.Controls.OfType(Of myPanel)()
```

Also, if you want to resize the dimensions of your panels to account for the presence of a vertical or horizontal scrollbar, you should avoid 'magic numbers' that will fail if the user adjust to its liking the display preferences of its system.
There are two properties in the WinForms namespace that give you the required value for the actual system

[HorizontalScrollBarHeigth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.horizontalscrollbarheight.aspx)
[VerticalScrollBarWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.verticalscrollbarwidth.aspx)